# Invalid array index not failing in php7 nginx phpfpm configuration

Tags: apache, nginx, php-7, php-5.6

Using the following code on a php5 machine running apache and mod_php causes an invalid index error as expected, but using it on php7 nginx with phpfpm does not.

```
<?php

  $test = [];
  echo $test['hello'];
```

Can anyone tell me why?  And if there's a way to tell phpfpm php7 to actually honor the error condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the person who created the docker container I was working with had set `error_reporting=E_ERROR` when it should have been `error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRICATED & ~E_STRICT`. This prevent the invalid index error from being thrown.